# How many eight-card hands from a standard deck have at least one suit missing?

Tags: combinatorics

How many eight-card hands from a standard deck have at least one suit missing?

How would I start this?
I thought it would be:
$\binom{4}1\times\binom{39}{8}$
where we pick one suit to discard, and then pick 8 cards from the remaining 39 cards...

Comment: This double-counts the number of hands with only spades and diamonds.

Comment: Would it also double count spades,diamonds and say hearts as well?

Comment: use the principle in inclusion-exclusion

Comment: Or count the number of hands that have all suits, and subtract that from the number of hands. I don't know whether that's easier.

Comment: @Arthur How would you do it this way? Since there seems to be so many options for the hands then (number of hands with all suits)

Comment: I must admit that I can't recall whether there is a good way to do it in this case. I just wanted to point out that when a combinatorics problem asks "how many ways have at least one of something" (in this case, at least one suit missing) you should immediately ask yourself whether it's easier to calculate "how many ways in total" and "how many ways have none of that something". Maybe you or someone else will think of a good way.

Answer (score 1):

As you determined, there are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to exclude one of the four suits and $\binom{39}{8}$ ways to choose $8$ cards from the $39$ cards of the other three suits.  However, the number $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{39}{8}$$ is too large since it counts hands with two suits missing twice and three suits missing thrice, once for each way of designating one of those suits as the missing suit.

There are $\binom{4}{2}$ to exclude two of the four suits and $\binom{26}{8}$ ways to choose eight cards from the two remaining suits.  If we subtract $\binom{4}{2}\binom{26}{8}$ from $\binom{4}{1}\binom{39}{8}$, we will obtain a number that is too small.  The reason is that we counted hands in which three suits are missing three times in our initial count, once for each way of designating one of the suits as the excluded suit, and subtracted them three times when we excluded hands with two suits missing, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of excluding two of the three missing suits.  Therefore, we have counted hands with three suits missing, so we need to add them back.

There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to exclude three of the four suits and $\binom{13}{8}$ ways to choose eight cards from the remaining suit.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of hands with at least one suit missing is 
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{39}{8} - \binom{4}{2}\binom{26}{8} + \binom{4}{3}\binom{13}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

Answer: $f(1) + f(2) + f(3)$

Where:

> $$
> f(n) = \left(\prod_{k = 13n}^{13n - 8}k\right)
> $$

Or:

> $$
> f(n) = 13n! - (13n - 8)!
> $$

and `n` are the number of suits; i.e.

- How many hands could have `1` suit: $f(1)$
- How many hands could have `4` suits: $f(4)$

Goals/Notes:

- `f` should get rid of the replica-card problem mentioned in the question's comments.
- `f` does **not** include joker face cards (change `13 -> 15` to include)

Comment: If only one suit is allowed, the number of combinations equals ${4 \choose 1} {13 \choose 8} = 5148$. However, $f(1) = 13! - 5! = 6227020680 \neq 5148$.

Comment: Order of selection does not matter here, just which cards are selected.